# Elastic Search - aggregation group by index

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have some indices with the same data type (same fields). Is there a way to get a max value (for example) of some field in every index?

Assume I have the following data:

```
index1.some_type:
    {"some_field": 23},
    {"some_field": 14},
    {"some_field": 43}

index2.some_type:
    {"some_field": 11},
    {"some_field": 65},
    {"some_field": 3}
```

I want to get max value 43 for the first index, and max value 65 for second. Elastic Search allows to do such a thing in one aggregation query?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, definitely you can use the special [`_index` meta field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html) in a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and then use the [`max` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) on `some_field`, like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_search -d '{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "byindex": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_value": {
          "max": {
            "field": "some_field"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: When there are large number of indexes, this doesn't return all indexes. Is there a way to force ES to look at all indexes and return them?

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran I've updated my answer (see the `size` parameter)